# Filter array of dictionary of array model in swift

Tags: swift

I have a data in below format

```
[["B": [MerchantModel(idString: 90046, squareImageUrlString: "https:images/2017-06-30_093600_1498815360_21897", rectangleImageUrlString: "https:/2017-06-30_093613_1498815373_26005", nameString: "Burger", stateDescriptionString: "Active")]], ["C": [MerchantModel(idString: 9000014, squareImageUrlString: "https:/2017-01-24_122206_1485260526_19795", rectangleImageUrlString: "https://017-01-24_122225_1485260545_43345", nameString: "Cape Union Mart", stateDescriptionString: "Active")]], ["D": [MerchantModel(idString: 9000021, squareImageUrlString: "https:/2016-09-23_132804_1474637284_33036", rectangleImageUrlString: "https://2016-09-23_132733_1474637253_16434", nameString: "Dis-Chem", stateDescriptionString: "Active")]], ["O": [MerchantModel(idString: 9000015, squareImageUrlString: "_46238", rectangleImageUrlString: "https://2017-03-03_114409_1488541449_86767", nameString: "Old Khaki", stateDescriptionString: "Active"), MerchantModel(idString: 9001108, squareImageUrlString: "https://2015-12-08_074852_1449560932_14101", rectangleImageUrlString: "https:/2015-12-08_074924_1449560964_32669", nameString: "Outdoor Warehouse", stateDescriptionString: "Active")]], ["P": [MerchantModel(idString: 9000020, squareImageUrlString: "https://latform.images/2017-10-20_070751_1508483271_24232", rectangleImageUrlString: "https://s3-eu-west-1.ws.com/2017-10-20_070802_1508483282_60598", nameString: "Primi", stateDescriptionString: "Active")]], ["S": [MerchantModel(idString: 9001078, squareImageUrlString: "https/2015-05-26_131716_1432646236_31314", rectangleImageUrlString: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/co.wigroup.global.wiplatform.images/2015-05-26_131726_1432646246_38768", nameString: "Steers", stateDescriptionString: "Active"), MerchantModel(idString: 9001102, squareImageUrlString: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/co.wigroup.global.wiplatform.images/2015-11-04_102848_1446632928_54414", rectangleImageUrlString: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/co.wigroup.global.wiplatform.images/2015-11-04_102909_1446632949_10764", nameString: "Sportsmans Warehouse", stateDescriptionString: "Active")]], ["T": [MerchantModel(idString: 9000051, squareImageUrlString: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/co.wigroup.global.wiplatform.images/2017-02-27_122839_1488198519_16635", rectangleImageUrlString: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/co.wigroup.global.wiplatform.images/2017-02-27_122858_1488198538_28922", nameString: "Tread and Miller", stateDescriptionString: "Active"), MerchantModel(idString: 9001132, squareImageUrlString: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/co.wigroup.global.wiplatform.images/2016-10-25_112853_1477394933_57183", rectangleImageUrlString: "2016-10-25_112909_1477394949_90719", nameString: "Total", stateDescriptionString: "Active"), MerchantModel(idString: 9001168, squareImageUrlString: "/2017-05-02_133525_1493732125_25733", rectangleImageUrlString: "2017-05-02_133546_1493732146_85357", nameString: "Toys R Us", stateDescriptionString: "Active"), MerchantModel(idString: 9001170, squareImageUrlString: "2017-05-11_090202_1494493322_33697", rectangleImageUrlString: "2017-05-11_090539_1494493539_29021", nameString: "Toy Kingdom", stateDescriptionString: "Active")]]]
```

Where `MerchantModel` is a model class as below

```
struct MerchantModel {
    let idString : UInt
    var squareImageUrlString : String
    let rectangleImageUrlString : String
    let nameString : String
    let stateDescriptionString : String

}
```

I have to perform search on given data in UISearchbar & I written below code

//MARK:- search merchants & reload table

```
func filter(array : [[String : [MerchantModel]]], byString filterString : String) {
    let searchByNamesArray = array.filter { $0.values.contains { $0.contains { $0.nameString.lowercased().contains(filterString.lowercased())} } }
    //Assign searched array into arrayOfMerchants
    self.arrayOfMerchants = searchByNamesArray
    //Reload table with new Data
    self.merchantTableView.reloadData()
}
```

above search method works fine for few case say 'Bu' in search bar with return 'Burger' but If I type 'Tr' in search bar I am getting wrong search.

Please suggest what am I doing wrong in search of data.

Please let me know if I have to explain my question.

Comment: thats too broad. What do you mean by `I type 'Tr' in search bar I am getting wrong search`? Are you getting wrong results or no result at all? be more specific

Comment: You have `"` missing in your data, in `"D"` in `squareImageUrlString`

Answer (score 1):

First of all the data format (array of dictionaries containing **one** key-value pair respectively) is very inefficient. A single dictionary containing all `[String:[MerchantModel]]` or a single array containing all `MerchantModel` items is much more efficient.

Nevertheless a possible efficient way to filter this format is first to get the appropriate dictionary for the prefix letter and then filter the values.

```
func filter(array : [[String : [MerchantModel]]], byString filterString : String) {

    var searchByNamesArray = [MerchantModel]()
    if let firstChar = filterString.first {
        let prefix = String(firstChar)
        if let modelDictionary = array.first(where: { $0[prefix] != nil }) {
            searchByNamesArray = modelDictionary[prefix]!.filter({$0.nameString.range(of: filterString, options:[.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil })
        } 
    }

    //Assign searched array into arrayOfMerchants
    self.arrayOfMerchants = searchByNamesArray

    //Reload table with new Data
    self.merchantTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `searchByNamesArray` is that it would return an array of dictionaries, and in this case, it is the one with the `"T"` key. The latter contains many merchants that may not match your search term.

Here is how you should do it:

```
let merchants: [MerchantModel] = data
    .map {Array($0.values)}
    .flatMap{$0}
    .flatMap{$0}
    .filter {$0.nameString.contains("Tr")}
```

So when the user searches for `"Tr"`, the result would be `"Tread and Miller"`:

```
let merchants: [MerchantModel] = data.map {Array($0.values)}.flatMap{$0}.flatMap{$0}.filter {$0.nameString.contains("Tr")}
merchants.forEach {print($0.nameString)} //Tread and Miller
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the questioner's function is expected to "return" a `[[String : [MerchantModel]]]`, not a `[MercantModel]`.